# How to work with checkbox using Groovy Templates and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, groovy

I am new to Groovy and trying to work with checkboxes. It is still checked even though completed is false.

```
tr {
    td("Completed")
    td(":")
    td {
        input(name: 'completed', type: 'checkbox', checked: todo.completed, value: todo.completed)
    }
    td(todo.completed)
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: It has been solved but waiting for the user to post an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll satisfy the immediate need:

```
if (todo.completed) {
    input(name: 'completed', type: 'checkbox', checked: selected, value: todo.completed ?: false)
} else {
    input(name: 'completed', type: 'checkbox', value: todo.completed ?: false)
}
```

It's ugly, but it works.

The key takeaway is the absence/presence of the "checked" attribute, as pointed out by [u/shivasprogeny](https://www.reddit.com/user/shivasprogeny/overview).

I'm curious *enough* to continue to pound against this and perhaps find a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, mate, it works for me. Take care.